# React - ES6 - this keyword and arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, this, arrow-functions

I have written a simple react code that just increases the value of 'numbers' when clicking on the button. It works well.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numbers: 1
    };
  }

handleClick = () =>{
  this.setState({
    numbers: this.state.numbers+1
  })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Incrementer</h1>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="increment" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <br/>
        <h1>{this.state.numbers}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have a query regarding the line:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="increment" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
```

When I change the above line as shown below, it still works:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="increment" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}/>
```

But, if I change it to

```
onClick={this.handleClick()}
```

or

```
onClick={handleClick()}
```

or

```
onClick={function clickFunction(){this.handleClick()}}
```

it does not compile.

onClick={() => this.handleClick()}

I'm not able to understand the difference. Kindly help.

Comment: Think about the difference between `var result = someFunc` vs `var result = someFunc()`

Comment: You need to allow React to call the `handleClick` function when the `click` event is triggered which can be done by providing a function to `onClick={<some function>}`. This `onClick={this.handleClick()}` calls the function and the result of calling `this.handleClick` is passed to `onClick`

Comment: `onClick={this.handleClick}` assigns the function `handleClick` to the click event, same happens with `onClick={() => this.handleClick()}`

But in `onClick={this.handleClick()}` its is calling the function `handleClick` directly while the template executes. If this function return something like a listner, that will be assigned to the click event. Or else the click event that you except to call on the click will be called directly on the template rendering

Comment: Thank you @Phil @Yousaf and @Nitheesh
I got it now.
I have one more question.

Aren't these two same?
`onClick={() => this.handleClick()} `
and
`onClick= {function x(){return  this.handleClick()}}`

Why does the second one doesn't work?

Comment: @GauthamMuralidharan the second one doesn't work because you're using a regular `function()`, which has it's own `this` binding. With an arrow function the `this` that is used is taken from the surrounding scope (ie: your class) but with a regular function, the `this` is determined based on how that function is invoked (which is done for you by react), so the `this` won't be your component/class